# How should I run game loop and change its objects?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am writing a game on OpenGL + C++.

The only way to generate animation is define an infinite loop inside `glutDisplayFunc`. And I did. But imagine I have different gameObjects, and   each one has its `draw()` function.

But I want a function to add another object. As I hold them in array of pointers, this function looks like this:

```
void display() {
    while (running) {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer
        if(objects_count != 0)
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i< objects_count - 1; i++) {
            (objects + i)->drawAsPoint();
        }
        glFlush();
        usleep(f60FPS);// Render now
    }
}

bool addRenderableObjectSync(GameEntity *object) {
    running = false;
    if(objects_count + 1>= objects_capacity) {
        //reallocating memory
        objects_capacity = round(objects_capacity * 1.5f);
        GameEntity * _new_objects = new GameEntity[objects_capacity];

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < objects_count; i++) {
            _new_objects[i] = objects[i];
        }
        //now objects are safe to delete free
        delete[] objects;
        //now we move new array to objects and free the temporary one
        objects = _new_objects;
        delete[] _new_objects;
    }

    objects[objects_count] = *object;
    objects_count++;

    //delete *object as it no longer needed;
    delete object;
    return true; }
```

`running` is a boolean which responses for loop inside display func.

BUT, draw-loop is infinite, i think that i need some async function which can hack `running` state, for example this:

```
void Renderer::addRenderableObject(GameEntity *object) {
    //the reason we do it cause a game is in infinite loop which never ends
    //so we stop the game, add an object, and after fn finish we let it run again
    std::future<bool> fut = std:: async(addRenderableObjectSync, object);
    running = fut.get();
}
```

Is that a right solution? Or there are better approaches?

Comment: You have 0 synchronization in your code. You won't be able to change anything safety asynchronously. Multithreading is a complex subject.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Could you please left an example of approach to this problem?

Comment: Your display function should not be an infinite loop. Glut will call the function set with `glutDisplayFunc` when rendering is needed. If this function never return you will block your thread forever.

A better idea would be to have a vector of GameObject (instead of allocating an array yourself) accessible both from the render callback and inputs callbacks (or somewhere else, this will be defined by your game according to when you need to add objects).